# Spinner dropdown selected value not visible - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm newbie to Android, i'm trying to design a spinner dropdown widget, the user selected value is not set as selected value in dropdown box [not display in marked area in below image].

[image]

**My design xml:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/propertyid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="160dip"
    android:padding="230dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

**Java code:**

```
private Spinner spin;
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
         spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.propertyid);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
        spin.setSelection(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            spin.setSelection(position);
         String item = list.get(position);
            System.out.println("&&&&&&----&&&&&&"+position+item);
            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Please anyone help me to get the selection list value displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just remove your**

```
android:padding="230dp"
```

**It is moving your item out of the boundary, 
All the rest codes are fine enough.**

Comment: It's common, Nothing to be worried, Its my pleasure.